# Arrange the blocks in a "grid" 3 x Y in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have some images and its descriptions, that I need to arrange in a kind of grid.

The main problem is that the image description should be **entirely visible**, so each line's height is determined by the bigger description.

[image]

Here is my CSS

```
.mediaContainer {
    margin:10px;
    width:600px;
}
.media {
    float:left;
    width:150px;
    margin:5px;
}
.picture {
    width:150px;
    height:100px;
}
.label {
    text-align:center;
}
```

The jsfiddle of the sample: http://jsfiddle.net/csYjC/2200/

Comment: What you will need is Masonary plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `float` use `display: inline-block`.

http://jsfiddle.net/csYjC/2201/

```
.media {
    width:150px;
    margin:5px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: @Mr.Alien How so?  Based on my understanding of the desired effect, my fiddle works just fine.  Masonry would pack the element in tight, which would not be a grid at all.

Comment: Seems like you got a down vote, not sure why but according to me, OP wants a filler space which floats or inline blocks wont be able to achieve, thats where masonary comes in, if OP has a huge description for a middle block, the space to the right bottom and left bottom will be wasted, he wants to move other elements to that empty space..

Comment: This isn't a complete wrong answer though, I'll settle up with an upvote

Comment: @Mr.Alien The use of the word "grid" and the line "each line's height is determined by the bigger description" leads me to a different understanding of what is desired.  With your understanding this would be wrong (as would the other posted answer), I guess the OP will have to explain.

Answer (score 3):

Use `:nth-child()`

```
.media:nth-child(3n-2) {
    clear: left;   
}
```

This selects every 3rd .media element and steps backward two elements for the final selection. Therefore, the first item out of every three items will be selected. You add a clear property to force that element to clear the other floated elements before it.

Comment: You are using `:nth-` on a class which is useless and also incorrect, nth pseudo doesn't respect classes

Comment: I understand the point you're making, but if the HTML is structured in a way that that all siblings of the parent element have the same class, the selection works. I could have also used ".mediaContainer > :nth-child(3n-2)" but ".media:nth-child(3n-2)" is less specific while getting the job done.

Comment: Yea, so its anyways concerned with the DOM order :)